# how to use vscode CompletionItemProvider by keybinding

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, monaco-editor

I tried to write an extension to vscode to help me import lib by keyboard shortcuts
I've tried many things, but two questions remain unanswered

> 1.How to use CompletionItemProvider by shortcut key

Normally, CompletionItemProvider is triggered by a character,But I want to be able to use the shortcut to bind commands.Ideally, I could press the shortcut to display the CompletionItems directly.But the only thing I know so far is through vscode.com command.excute('trugger suggest'), which can be cluttered with other CompletionItems

> 2.How to hide other CompletionItems

When trigger the CompletionItemProvider,other options appear . They should come from other extensions .What should I do to display only my own extension options

**code:**

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    const provider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider({
        scheme:"file",
        language:"typescript"
    }, {
        provideCompletionItems(doc, pos) {
            return [
                new vscode.CompletionItem("1.foo"),
                new vscode.CompletionItem("2.bar"),
                new vscode.CompletionItem("3.baz")
            ]
        }
    })

    context.subscriptions.push(provider);
}
```

**result:out of the red box are unnecessary options**

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible.